# Binding string lists into wpf listview returns BindingExpression path error

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I've two string lists declared as below:

Config.cs:

```
public class AgentSkills 
{
  public List<string> agentSkillsNameList=new List<string>();
  public List<string> agentSkillsLvlList=new List<string>();
}
```

I retrieved the strings from an XML and added them to the lists as below:

Config.cs:

```
foreach (XmlNode skillNameNode in skillNameNodeList) 
{
  agentSkills.agentSkillsNameList.Add(skillNameNode.Attributes["value"].Value);
}

foreach (XmlNode skillLevelNode in skillLevelNodeList) 
{
  agentSkills.agentSkillsLvlList.Add(skillLevelNode.Attributes["value"].Value);
}
```

Then, I passed those list and bound them into a listview like this:

Info.cs:

```
Config.AgentSkills abc = new Config.AgentSkills();

this.AInfoLv.Items.Add(new { Label=" " + abc.agentSkillsNameList, Value=" " + abc.agentSkillsLvlList });
```

But it returns errors as below:

```
System.Windows.Data Error:40:BindingExpression path error:'Value' property not found on'object'''<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=2053256737)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value;
 DataItem='<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=2053256737);
 target element is'TextBlock' (Name='');
 target property is'Text' (type'String') 
System.Windows.Data Error:40:BindingExpression path error:'Value' property not found on'object'''<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=-861434965)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value;
 DataItem='<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=-861434965);
 target element is'TextBlock' (Name='');
 target property is'Text' (type'String') 
System.Windows.Data Error:40:BindingExpression path error:'Value' property not found on'object'''<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=1323488897)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value;
 DataItem='<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=1323488897);
 target element is'TextBlock' (Name='');
 target property is'Text' (type'String') 
System.Windows.Data Error:40:BindingExpression path error:'Value' property not found on'object'''<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=-2018970060)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value;
 DataItem='<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=-2018970060);
 target element is'TextBlock' (Name='');
 target property is'Text' (type'String') 
System.Windows.Data Error:40:BindingExpression path error:'Value' property not found on'object'''<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=249974195)'. BindingExpression:Path=Value;
 DataItem='<>f__AnonymousType0`1' (HashCode=249974195);
 target element is'TextBlock' (Name='');
 target property is'Text' (type'String')
```

Is it ok to bind string lists into a listview in wpf? If can't, is there any suggestion on this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you aren't binding a list of strings to a `ListView`, you are binding an `IEnumerable<String>` to a `TextBlock.Text` field, when it is expecting a `String` as you can see in the errors.

The fastest way to solve your problem is to change the line to

```
this.AInfoLv.Items.Add(new { 
   Label=" " + string.Join(", ", abc.agentSkillsNameList), 
   Value=" " + string.Join(", ", abc.agentSkillsLvlList) 
});
```

Comment: Hi @AlSki, thanks for your solution. Instead of display the string like: a,b,c...how can I display them in different line, which is like:
a
b
c

Comment: I found it out already, replace ", " with System.Environment.NewLine...thanks for your solution again :)